# How to set focus on JMenu?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, focus

I have a JFrame with `JMenuBar` and JMenus in it.
When I run the frame I want a focus to be set in `JMenu`, so when I hit `space` button it will show its MenuItems.

these all doesn't work

```
mnNewMenu_1.requestFocus();
mnNewMenu_1.grabFocus();
mnNewMenu_1.requestFocusInWindow();
```

How to make a default focus set on the JMenu when the app is run?

Here is the sources:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JButton;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GUIsds extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                    GUIsds frame = new GUIsds();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public GUIsds() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JMenu mnNewMenu = new JMenu("New menu");
        menuBar.add(mnNewMenu);

        JMenuItem mntmNewMenuItem = new JMenuItem("New menu item");
        mnNewMenu.add(mntmNewMenuItem);

        JMenu mnNewMenu_1 = new JMenu("New menu2");
        menuBar.add(mnNewMenu_1);

        JMenuItem mntmNewMenuItem_1 = new JMenuItem("New menu item2");
        mnNewMenu_1.add(mntmNewMenuItem_1);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you try to call those methods?

Comment: @Ferrybig after menuBar.add(mnNewMenu_1);

Comment: Can you try to do it at the end of the constructor? It may that they require a valid frame before they have any effect.

Comment: @Ferrybig doesn't work(

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure the frame is visible before you try to display the menu. So you can try something like:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        mnNewMenu_1.doClilck();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you set the focus on the frame (in other cases I supose the parent Panel or Componect would work), <kbd>SPACE</kbd> no longer activates the button:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
                GUIsds frame = new GUIsds();
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setFocusable(true); //added this
        }
    });
}
```

After that you can add KeyListener to your frame at the end of GUIsds() to have menu show up :

```
  this.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
         public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
           int key = e.getKeyCode();

           if (key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
               System.out.println("SPACE");
              mnNewMenu_1.doClick();
           }
           }
         }
      );
```

Alternatively, as a much simpler solution if you don't mind pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> you can use `setMnemonic()` inside `GUIsds()` :

```
mnNewMenu_1.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
```